# How to serialize / deserialize this AWS API with F#?

Tags: json, serialization, f#, fleece

AWS has the following API for DNS records:

```
{
  "ResourceRecordSets": [
    {
      "Name": "domain.tld.",
      "ResourceRecords": [
        {
          "Value": "ns-583.awsdns-08.net."
        },
        {
          "Value": "ns-1176.awsdns-19.org."
        }
      ],
      "TTL": 172800,
      "Type": "NS"
    },
    {
      "AliasTarget": {
        "DNSName": "hello.cloudfront.net.",
        "EvaluateTargetHealth": false,
        "HostedZoneId": "XYZ2123"
      },
      "Name": "some.domain.tld.",
      "Type": "A"
    }
  ]
}
```

I was trying to serialize / deserialize it with Fleece, which is an amazing tool for JSON.

```
type AliasTarget = {
    DNSName               : string
    EvaluateTargetHealth  : bool
    HostedZoneId          : string
  }
  with
    static member JsonObjCodec =
      fun d e h -> { DNSName = d; EvaluateTargetHealth = e; HostedZoneId = h }
      |> withFields
      |> jfield    "DNSName"                (fun d -> d.DNSName)
      |> jfield    "EvaluateTargetHealth"   (fun e -> e.EvaluateTargetHealth)
      |> jfield    "HostedZoneId"           (fun h -> h.HostedZoneId)

  type ResourceRecord =
    { Value : string }
    with
      static member JsonObjCodec =
        fun r -> { Value = r }
        |> withFields
        |> jfield "Value" (fun r -> r.Value)

  type ResourceRecords =
    List<ResourceRecord>

  type ResourceRecordsOrAlias =
    | AliasTarget of
        AliasTarget
    | ResourceRecords of
        ResourceRecords
    with
      static member JsonObjCodec =
        (
          ( AliasTarget     <!> jreq "AliasTarget"      (function AliasTarget a     -> Some a | _ -> None) )
        <|>
          ( ResourceRecords <!> jreq "ResourceRecords"  (function ResourceRecords r -> Some r | _ -> None) )
        )

  type ResourceRecordSet =
    {
      Name            : string
      RecordsOrAlias  : ResourceRecordsOrAlias
      TTL             : Option<uint32>
      Type            : string
    }
    with
      static member JsonObjCodec =
        fun n r tt ty -> { Name = n; RecordsOrAlias = r; TTL =tt; Type = ty}
        |> withFields
        |> jfield "Name"            (fun n  -> n.Name)
        // error
        |> jchoice [
          AliasTarget       <!> jfield "AliasTarget"      (fun r  -> r.RecordsOrAlias)
          ResourceRecords   <!> jfield "ResourceRecords"  (fun r  -> r.RecordsOrAlias)
        ]
        |> jfieldOpt "TTL"          (fun tt -> tt.TTL)
        |> jfield "Type"            (fun ty -> ty.Type)
```

It seems that I cannot branch in the final codec. I have tried a few different options. Is there a way to

Comment: I see what's wrong. You are mixing `Codec` with `ConcreteCodec`. The former is used for the "verbose syntax" and the latter for the operators style.

Comment: Thanks Gus. I am open to change it either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using the latest version (at the moment) which is 0.8 of Fleece.

The first problem I see is that you are mixing in the same methods, the operator approach (`jchoice` belongs to it) and the verbose one. It is fine to use different styles in different methods, but not on the same one.

This at the moment is tricky as for historical reasons they use different types, so they can't be mixed like this.

However, once you sort that out it will take you to the next problem: you are not being able to re-use the DU, as using a normal `jreq {tagname}` will create a tag that encompass the DU fields, but looking at the json sample that's not what you need. You need to insert it directly, without creating a new tag.

I can propose you this function to do that:

```
let jfrom codec f = Codec.compose (Codec.ofConcrete codec) (Ok, f) |> Codec.toConcrete
```

(and will propose it to Fleece as well).

This function maps (or more properly contramaps) on the input of the encoder.

In your case you'll use this function to map on the input of the encoder from `ResourceRecordsOrAlias`, in order to encode from a `ResourceRecordSet` instead.

So, your method will be:

```
static member JsonObjCodec =
  fun n r tt ty -> { Name = n; RecordsOrAlias = r; TTL =tt; Type = ty}
  <!> jreq "Name" (fun n  -> Some n.Name)
  <*> jfrom ResourceRecordsOrAlias.JsonObjCodec (fun r -> r.RecordsOrAlias)
  <*> jopt "TTL"  (fun tt -> tt.TTL)
  <*> jreq "Type" (fun ty -> Some ty.Type)
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the JSON type provider?

https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/JsonProvider.html

Your sample

```
[<Literal>]
let amazonSample = """
{
  "ResourceRecordSets": [
    {
      "Name": "domain.tld.",
      "ResourceRecords": [
        {
          "Value": "ns-583.awsdns-08.net."
        },
        {
          "Value": "ns-1176.awsdns-19.org."
        }
      ],
      "TTL": 172800,
      "Type": "NS"
    },
    {
      "AliasTarget": {
        "DNSName": "hello.cloudfront.net.",
        "EvaluateTargetHealth": false,
        "HostedZoneId": "XYZ2123"
      },
      "Name": "some.domain.tld.",
      "Type": "A"
    }
  ]
}
"""
```

declaring the type provider

```
type Amazon = JsonProvider<amazonSample,RootName="ResourceRecordSets">
```

Deserializing

```
let r = Amazon.Parse(amazonSample)

printfn "%s" r.ResourceRecordSets.[1].AliasTarget.Value.DnsName
```

Serializing

```
let alias = new Amazon.AliasTarget( "hello.cloudfront.net.",false,"XYZ2123")
let res1 = new Amazon.ResourceRecord( "ns-583.awsdns-08.net.")
let record1 = new Amazon.ResourceRecordSet2( "domain.tld.", [|res1|], Some(342), "NS", Some(alias))
let recordSet = new Amazon.ResourceRecordSet( [|record1|] )

printfn "%s" (recordSet.JsonValue.ToString())
```

Comment: Yes, could you show me how I could actually use it for this problem?

Comment: @Istvan see above